# Which is more efficient and secured way, post connection or direct connection to a database?

Tags: android, ios, http-post, memory-efficient, database-connection

I want to insert many data to a mysql database, only text of course.

I'm currently doing via post, for example `insertUser.php?user=asd&pass=asdas&email=asdasd` and it will give me a response if it was ok or not, but now I'm trying to `upload` a giant amount of data like `insertData.php?xml=string&userid=2` and the response it's big too and sometimes it will take long time because it's for mobile phone applications mostly using **3g (android & iOS)**, so which will be more efficient, still doing `post connections` or a `direct mysql connection`?

Thanks.

Comment: i hope you will have to use background process as its a time intensive process .. check multipart upload for huge data like images and files

Comment: better to use "POST" method to post data to server. As you are using "GET" method to do so but "GET" method has some length limitation as I think. Even "POST" is secure than "GET".

Comment: Well I'm using POST but I typed like GET.

Comment: While you are using "POST" then better to post data in body instead using url.

Comment: Ok @sanjitshaw do you have an ios or android example? thanks.

Comment: So, you need a sample code to post data using "POST"

Comment: Not really, I need to send data in body throught post, because I'm sending through post with url (called GET, but it's not a real get because the PHP will not recognize any get parameter)

Comment: @rokimoki check my answer. On that way I am posting data to server in body using "POST"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the answer below

```
xmlbody = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                        NULL,
                                                                            (CFStringRef)xmlbody,
                                                                            NULL,
                                                                            (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                                            kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );

NSMutableString *entirexmlbody=[[NSMutableString alloc]init ];
[entirexmlbody appendString:@"xml="];
[entirexmlbody appendString:xmlbody];

NSLog(@"posting XML Body after encoding--%@\n",xmlbody);

NSData *postData = [entirexmlbody dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:posturl]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection *conn=[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];
```

Comment: Thanks i think this will work, should I do this in a thread? or... for example If I have to send a 100mb file (of course it won't be like that) it will be uploaded? and if the response is about 100mb of text file, it will be responsed without a null response?

Comment: I think {NSURLConnection} already creates a separate thread so I think no need to create another thread. And 100mb is huge data I haven't tested ever with that much of data or response.

Comment: I have this code, is it the same? the last line you use a `NSURLConnection` but I'm doing `NSURLResponse` http://pastebin.com/2M9bAjwg

Comment: In your code you are using synchronous connection but I'm using asynchronous connection.

Comment: and what's the difference? I mean I wanted to know which is more efficient, thank you a lot. @sanjitshaw

Comment: @rokimoki If you use asynchronous connection then it won't stuck your main thread but if you use synchronous connection then your main thread will stuck until the task is complete. If you want to know more about both connection type just go through any networking tutorial book you will get a fine idea.